# ggplot2, layered plots reversing order

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am combining ggplots, plot A and B, like this, but how do I make plot b, the layers, come to be on the top, by simply switching them I stuck on the error `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. If I should combine my data or do it some smarter way, I am very open to that too.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


data_A <- data.frame(id=rep(c("1", "2"), each=3*4),
            time=rep(ordered(c("A", "1", "2", "3"), levels = c("A", "1", "2", "3")),3*2),
            val_lines=c(0.6, 0.36, 0.15, 0.09,
                    0.6, 0.35, 0.13, 0.07,
                    0.6, 0.31, 0.10, 0.05,
                    0.75, 0.70, 0.30, 0.15,
                    0.75, 0.65, 0.25, 0.10,
                    0.75, 0.60, 0.20, 0.05),
            grp=rep(rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=4), 2))

plot_A <- ggplot(data_A, aes(time, val_lines, colour = grp, group=grp)) +
  geom_line()+ geom_point()  + facet_grid(cols = vars(id))
plot_A

time <- as.numeric(rep(seq(1, 4), each = 5))                # x Axis
value1 <- rep(c(0.05, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.125), times = 4)   # y Axis grp 1
value2 <- rep(c(0.02, 0.1, 0.12, 0.125, 0.14), times = 4)   # y Axis grp 1
group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), times = 4)         # group, one shape per group

one <- data.frame(time, val = value1, group)
two <- data.frame(time, val = value2, group)

# Bind the two datasets together
data_B <- bind_rows(one, two, .id = "id")

# Combine both datasets and create a single plot using ggplot2
combined_plot <- ggplot() +
  # Plot for data_A
  geom_line(data = data_A, aes(time, val_lines, colour = grp, group = grp)) +
  geom_point(data = data_A, aes(time, val_lines, colour = grp, group = grp)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(id)) +
  # Plot for data_B
  geom_area(data = data_B, alpha = 0.5, aes(x = time, y = val, fill = group)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 3)

# Display the combined plot
print(combined_plot)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply plot the layers first, and add `scale_x_discrete()` to your plot.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = data_B, alpha = 0.5, aes(x = time, y = val, fill = group)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 3) +
  geom_line(data = data_A, aes(time, val_lines, colour = grp, group = grp)) +
  geom_point(data = data_A, aes(time, val_lines, colour = grp, group = grp)) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(id)) +
  scale_x_discrete()
```

[image]

Note though, that the problem comes about because the `time` variable is different in the two columns; in `data_A` it is an ordered factor and in `data_B` it is numeric. Forcing the `scale_x_discrete` will make the x axis take the values of `time` in `data_A`, and convert the values of the numeric `time` column in `data_B` to the equivalent *levels* in the discrete `time` column in `data_A` (i.e. 1 = "A", 2 = "1", 3 = "2", 4 = "3"). It makes much more sense to me to convert one of the `time` columns so that its type matches the other one. Plotting the two together implies that there is an equivalence, so why not take the small step of making that equivalence explicit?

Comment: Thanks for a great anwer, including a good question. I would much prefer to follow your logic, and have `time` in `data_B` be non-numeric. I take I could get that by coding time like this, `time <- rep(c("A", "1", "2", "3"), each = 5)`. Could you possible show me, as an extra thing, how I would go about writing the rest of the code if `time` in `data_B` was a character or a factor variable?

Comment: @EricFail if time was a factor or character in data_B, the above plotting code should work just fine.